# ntheorem and hyperref at pagebreaks

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ntheorem

It seems that hyperref and theorem do not cope together very well whenever a theorem happens to start at the beginning of a new page. Clicking a hyperlink to such a theorem leads to a jump to the end of the previous page.

amsthm seems to work fine without any additional adjustments. It also seems that a manual \clearpage command works as a dirty fix for ntheorem. Obviously, this is a very fragile solution. Is there a better way around that?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem} % leads to wrong hyperlink positions
%\usepackage{amsthm} % works fine
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{testthm}{Test Theorem}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{testthm} \label{test}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{testthm}
Works with amsthm, but not with ntheorem: \ref{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The simple solution is not using `ntheorem`.

Comment: @egreg -- I *knew* you were going to say that. :-)